# Clubbing in Liverpool

Tags: recommendations, nightlife, liverpool

I am going to Liverpool next Friday with four other friends and was wondering where could we get the best value for money clubbing experience?

I read that Heebie Jeebies was good, but recent reviews state that the service and atmosphere are not that great anymore. I also heard about Chibuku, and Cavern Club (of course), but paying £20 to get in those seems quite expensive.

[EDIT] As we are international students, the kind of music is the least we are concerned about, as long as the atmosphere is good (for clubbing of course), we are open to rock, house, electro, indie, etc. We are going to pre-drink, so we are willing to pay up to £12 to get in.

Comment: Welcome to the Travel.SE. Unfortunately, this kind of question is very broad and and can't answered for the one right answer.

Comment: @VMAtm: I think clubbing is a valid question for Travel-SE -- I've travelled to specific cities to enjoy the music scene in a certain genre. For example -- Bristol is kind of the birthplace of trip-hop, and many bands and performers started from there. But you are right the question is too broad as it stands. Perhaps a better approach would be to ask the OP for clarification what particular music style he's interested in, and that kind of question can be answered reasonably well.

Comment: I'm going to ask about this on meta later and state my case.

Comment: @mindcorrosive Yes, I think this question must be closed not as off-top, but as not constructive.

Comment: @arturhoo: Your question, as it stands, is too broad and not easily answered. I suggest you edit your question to include: 1) what music styles and genres you and your friends prefer (mentioning specific artists will help as well); 2) As you mention you don't want to pay too much, specify the maximum amount you'd be willing to spend (for e.g. entrance + a drink). Then your question will be reasonably answerable, and I will try to convince mods to reopen it.

Comment: Agreed. If the question scope is focussed, then this case definitely be re-opened.

Comment: @Toni Frankola Disagree - the reason for the close is written. If the question will be focussed, we will reopen it.

Comment: It's also very subjective.  There's no one right answer.  Some may like certain clubs and be against others.  Agree - it's travel related (just barely but sure) but it's too subjective for a Stackexchange question.  If re-written and refocused, probably could be reopened.

Comment: I don't agree with closing. I don't think the OP wants one perfectly right and fitting answer. He just wants to get some tips to choose from. That's the point. This is not a mathematical rebus, but a question that comes up in life.

Comment: I mean, of course different people will have different opinions, but I think that a local would be able to say which places not to go, and which places that a tourist would enjoy.

Comment: Edited and a bit more focused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't been out clubbing in Liverpool. However, [Liverpool City Guides' listing of clubs in Liverpool](http://www.liverpoolcityguide.co.uk/liverpool-clubbing.html) seems to provide an overview of cover charge you can expect at each club and the genres played there, which you may find useful.